# Angular: Bind function to html from constant

Tags: html, angular, function, typescript

In Angular i have some template defined as a constant, The template renders fine and all, but I want to attach an event to an element from the html constant. It doesn't seem like i can bind the function as I would normally do when the template is defined in the @Component definition.

Here is a stripped piece of code describing what I have tried.

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    public ngOnInit(): void {
        const someHtml = `
          <a (click)="someFunction()" href="someUrl">link</a>
        `
        .. some code that uses the const
    }

    public someFunction() {
        console.log("clicked")
    }
}
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: Could you elaborate more ? a stackblitz would be helpful :)

Comment: I want the event 'someFunction()' to fire. Will make an stack blitz

Comment: This really isn’t the “angular way” of doing things. What is the actual use case here? Why are you trying to do this instead of using actual templates and components

Comment: @JonasPraem thanks, just want to know how do u render what is affected to the `const`..

Comment: It is used in a google.maps.InfoWindow `const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: someHtml,
            maxWidth: 450
        });`